# I think I have entered some sort of mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#

I have recently started my project and while I was copying over some code provided, none of the pasted code was registering as code. If I started typing "if", it would come up with a drop down box that would allow me to select different code pre-sets although the code would remain plain white text:
[image: .]

Any idea on what I accidentally pressed? Is it a keyboard shortcut which entered me into some sort of editor mode?

I am using C# in Visual Studio Code

whole window:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're having a syntax error, you're missing an open curly brace in line 12 after `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)`.

You're also missing a clear closing brace in this method after line 19 so you should definitely fix what's going on with this method.

Structural syntax errors like this typically confuse IDEs to some extend based on how good their error handling is, and provide none or confusing auto completion or coloring.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you're missing are the curly brackets to indicate the method body.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the right to give comments on a question 